# Getstylesheets is giving a nullpointerexception in Javafx, how do I fix this?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I am well aware that this question has been asked before (several times), but I've reviewed the 'solutions' on what I could find ([adding css file to stylesheets in javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946372/adding-css-file-to-stylesheets-in-javafx), [Loading css using JavaFX null pointer exception in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237043/loading-css-using-javafx-null-pointer-exception-in-eclipse), [CSS stylesheet not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576858/css-stylesheet-not-loading)) and nothing has seemed to work.

Here is the line of code in question:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("MainMenu.css").toExternalForm()); //this code gives a nullpointerexception
```

In every other project I have had this code has worked fine, so I don't understand what the problem is. The only difference I can think of is that this is within a git repository.

To answer some questions that I've seen asked:

Yes, I have initialized the scene, the scene is not the problem and the program runs fine without the line of code above.

Yes, I have tried adding a backslash before the name. It did not work

Yes, the css file is in the same folder as the .java file

Yes, I have included the package at the top of the .java file

The file is purely named "MainMenu.css", not "MainMenu.css.txt" or "MainMenu.css.css"

I can't for the life of me understand where the problem is. Is it a typo? Did I miss something? Help would really be appreciated.

If it helps any, I'm using Java 8 with Maven through Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in `getClass()` which resolves resources relative to the *path* of the class.

So `getClass().getResource("MainMenu.css")` will resolve to the correct URL only if is in the same *package dir* of the class of the object which is using that instruction.

So if `MainMenu.css` is in the same *package* (directory) of a `MainMenuView` class, just use `MainMenuView.getResource("MainMenu.css")` , otherwise you can always use absolute paths, like

`getClass().getResource("/org/mycompany/myapp/view/MainMenu.css")`

### Update

Maven could also be the reason why you could not find your *resource* file.

Maven does not *move* resources placed in the `src/main/java` folder into the *target/classes* folder.

It does move resources in the `src/main/resources` folder.

If you have a standard maven layout this could lead resources missing.

You could, in that case, use the maven-resource-plugin to include those resources in your build.

For example, in one project I had to add this plugin configuration for the build.

```xml
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-fxml-resources</id>
                        <!-- here the phase you need -->
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/java/</directory>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/*.fxml</include>
                                        <include>**/*.css</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I needed the resources in the `src/main/java` folder, because otherwise the Scene Builder would not find them.

Comment: Both the css and the class are in the same package dir as each other. Thanks for the suggestion but I tried both and they didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Did you put the resources in the resource folder? Check in the target/classes folder.

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't in there. Thanks for the help. It is strange though because maven-resources-plugin should be copying the files over automatically should it not?

Comment: It does if they are in the resources folder, but not in the java folder.

Comment: It's strange though because this worked fine with previous projects. Why would it not work now?

Comment: To reply to this I would have to know the details of both the current and past projects.